# How to make all characters lowercase in NSString?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring

How would I go about making all characters in an NSString lowercase?

Comment: That's not very helpful, he may not even have known about it. How about recommending that he google "NSString Reference" in the future?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html) has a cunningly named `lowercaseString` method.

```
NSString *noCaps = [yourString lowercaseString];
```

**Edited to add**

If you are asking how to change the *actual* string to be lowercase - you can't. NSStrings are immutable. They can't be changed after they have been created. If you want to change the string in place you should use an NSMutableString like so:

```
[aMutableString setString:[aMutableString lowercaseString]];
```